# How is $R^2$ calculated in the lavaan package for structural equation modeling?

Tags: lavaan, structural-equation-modeling

I am doing a study for which I tested a model like this:

Model1: Var1 --> var2--> var3 --> var4. All variables are latent variables and have several indicators.

Now, the $R^2$ of var3 is 0.4 in this case. However, something strange happens when I test the model:

Model2: Var1 --> var2 --> var3.

In this case, although the variables BEFORE var3 remain exactly the same, the $R^2$ of var3 becomes much smaller (0.28).

Does anyone have a possible explanation for this? How does lavaan package in R calculate $R^2$? Especially for mediating variables like var3 in this case? The indicators for var3 remain the same. I've already checked whether this is due to missings in var4 but this is not the case.

Answer (score 4):

In Lavaan, $R^2$ is a byproduct of the other parameters, it's not a parameter that is directly calculated. So $R^2$ for Var3 depends on the variance of var3, and the size of the path from var2 to var3. And these all depend on the loading.

When you add something to a model (var4) this can have effects all over the model - people sometimes talk about mis-specification 'flowing through the model'. Let's say that var2 and var4 are not correlated, but var2 and var3 are correlated, and var3 and var4 are correlated. If the estimates stay the same, the predicted correlation between var2 and var3 will be too high, so these the var2-> var3 estimate is reduced, lowering  $R^2$, and this would be indicated by a lack of fit.

Comment: Great answer. OP might see whether the variance of var2, the coefficient for the effect of var2 on var3, and the error variance of var3 remain the same before and after including var4.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is sometimes known as 'interpretational confounding' (Burt, 1976). The problem is that the model does not distinguish between structural and measurement parameters so simply optimises over all parameters. Thus, if an item is more closely related to a different latent variable than the average of other items on the factor, then the loading of that item on its latent variable will increase to improve the fit of the model. This means that the latent variables are partly defined by indicators from other scales in the model, and when a new scale is added the interpretation of the latent variables changes.

In the case of the question, adding (or removing) var4 resulted in the interpretation of (at least) var3 changing, which meant a different amount of its variance was predicted by var2.

This is a serious issue that it is important to do something about. It may be possible to overcome by allowing correlated residuals fairly liberally (so these relationships don't spread through the latent variables) but this is far from perfect. A relatively easy way to deal with the issue simply forces the measurement parameters to match the values in CFAs (by fixing them in the model specification). The coolest method, though, is to allow item residuals to correlate with all other latent variables and then constrain these in some way. If the sum of squares of item residual correlations with external factors is minimised (for each factor combination) then the measurement parameters equal what they would have been in a CFA (Nagy et al., 2017). This method does get out of hand when there are lots of items or factors and is complicated so simply fixing parameters is usually the best method from a pragmatic point of view.

http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/004912417600500101

http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/00220973.2016.1260524